# how to store the content of variable into const char*?

Tags: c++

i have a pointer or variable which stores the address like `0xb72b218` now i have to store this value in to `const char*`. how i can store it. Thanks in advance.
I tried following:
suppose i have a pointer variable "ptr" which contains `0xb72b218` value

```
ostringstream oss;
oss << ptr;
string buf = oss.str();
const char* value = buf.c_str();
```

but it is more complicated any one know easy way.

Comment: It's unusual to store values in this way - can you elaborate why you need to do this?

Comment: @trojanfoe i need to pass the const char* argument to other function. the function prototype is fixed.

Comment: I think stringstream makes your task more easy than complicated.

Comment: What is the function you need to pass the `const char*` to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... if you really want the address of something in a string, this will do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
  char buf[30];
  void* ptr = /*your pointer here*/;
  snprintf(buf,sizeof(buf),"%p",ptr);

  std::cout << "pointer as string: " << buf << "\n";
  std::cout << "pointer as value: " << ptr << "\n";
}
```

Or if you don't like magic numbers and want your code to work even when 256bit pointers are nothing special anymore, try this:

```
#include <limits>  // for numeric_limits<T>
#include <stdint.h>  // for intptr_t
#include <stdio.h>  // for snprintf
#include <iostream>

int main(){
  int i;
  int* ptr = &i; // replace with your pointer
  const int N = std::numeric_limits<intptr_t>::digits;
  char buf[N+1]; // +1 for '\0' terminator
  snprintf(buf,N,"%p",ptr);

  std::cout << "pointer as string: " << buf << "\n";
  std::cout << "pointer as value: " << static_cast<void*>(ptr) << "\n";
}
```

[Example on Ideone](http://ideone.com/APWKL).

Comment: @Konrad: You mean the size of the buffer? Well yeah, it was just an example. Could make it more complicated with `numeric_limits` hackery. :P

Comment: @Xeo Exactly. *If* you insist on a static buffer and `snprintf`, then you *should* use `numeric_limits` to retrieve the correct buffer size.

Comment: Shouldn't that be char buf[N+1], +1 for null termination?

Comment: @luke: Oooops, you didn't see that! ;)

Comment: How is this less complicated than the original solution that OP has in his question ?

Comment: @Arun: See the edit history, it *was* less complicated but @Konrad complained about "magic numbers". ;) Edited the uncomplicated version back in.

Comment: `numeric_limits<>::digits` gives the number of non-sign bits, not the number of hex digits. Also, `"%p"` doesn't necessarily give a simple hexadecimal representation, so something more complicated based on `numeric_limits` or `sizeof` won't necessarily give the correct size either.

Answer (score 0):

OK, presumably there must some additional parameter that tells the function what type of data is actually being passed, but you can do it like this:

```
extern void afunc(const char *p, int type);

int value = 1234;
afunc((const char *)&value, TYPE_INT);
```

Comment: @Konrad: Maybe it was and the questioner got the problem wrong. Maybe he needs to pass a pointer to a function that operatos on bytes? Who knows, that's why I made that comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at `const_cast`? It is a means of adding/removing const-ness from a variable in C++. Take a look [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/keyword_const_cast.htm).

Comment: How is that relevant here? The question isn’t about `const`ness and it’s not even really about casting.